# How to hide the Flagged folder in Mail.app (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, google-apps

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, my Mail.app has sprouted a **Flagged** folder for each of my Gmail/Google Apps accounts.

[image]

I have no use for this and would like to disable or hide it - how can I do that?

To pre-empt some answers, no, this is not a folder that exists in either Gmail account, it's something that Mail.app has made up for itself, much like a **Smart Folder**.

Comment: The Flagged folder do sync against Gmail's "Starred" mails in any folder on your Gmail account. As long as you can see the mails that are starred, it will show up in the Flagged folder.

Comment: So if I hide the Starred folder from IMAP, they should disappear? Worth a try.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. I do use flags/stars, but I do not want them to show up in that folder.

Comment: Just hiding the "Starred" folder wont help as Mail.app takes these mails from all folders on your Gmail account that are shared on the IMAP. So sadly it would take you to remove all folders from IMAP that contain any "Starred" mails. Pretty stupid yes.

Comment: @Hoshts thank you so much for this, it was driving me crazy with my work email couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drove me crazy too, so I made a mailbundle to right this wrong ;-)  Download it here:
http://eelco.lempsink.nl/NoFlaggedMailbox.zip

Note: I’ll update the plugin every time when Mail.app breaks it for ‘compatibility’ reasons.  Just download it again and run the INSTALL script again to update.  (Might take me a couple of days though.)

Comment: Awesome! Sadly I can't get it to work. Mail seems to load it as far as I can tell (no error at least), but the dreaded Flagged folder stays. Any ideas?

Comment: Right, I forgot, you need to enable mailbundles by executing in Terminal.app: defaults write com.apple.mail EnableBundles -bool true

Comment: I've updated the .zip to include that instruction.

Comment: Okay, I've now included an 'installer' in the zip.  Open it and everything will happen automatically ;)

Comment: Ah, didn't know about EnableBundles - that did it! Many thanks for this :)

Comment: Thanks dude! No more flagged mail :-D I love you :-)